# Selecting an Option in HTML select control with runat server enabled, using asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I've HTML select control on my page with 30-40 options. I enabled the runat="server" and had given an ID say mySelect.
But my requirement is to select an option on this select control from code behind.

I tried 
    mySelect.value= "10"

Didnt worked

then tried

```
Dim li as new listitem
li=myselect.items.findbyvalue("10")
li.selected=true
```

Didnt helped me

Only situation I was able to make it work was using

```
mySelect.selectedindex=5
```

So how can I select the element using Value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the list value by item then select it as follows:

**Codebehind**

```
var listItem = mySelect.Items.FindByValue("value3").Selected = true;
```

**Markup**

```
<select id="mySelect" runat="server">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes.. I did the same  (As I mentioned in my question)... But strange its not working.. Am still digging on it..

Comment: @sforsandeep The above works fine for me. You've not got ViewState disabled at page level or anything have you?